# how to add and remove custom elements on the fly or by an click event in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Almost give up on Aurelia, I'm struggling with adding custom elements dynamic in Aurelia,
lets say we have a custom tag:
view my-element.html:

```
<template>  My Element ${name} </template>
```

viewmodel: my-element.js:

```
export class MyElement {
    @bindable name = '';
}
```

so I try to manually add this tag, in another view:

```
<template>
<button type="button" click.delegate="createMyElement()">Remove</button>
</template>
```

another viewmodel:

```
export class App {

   createMyElement() {
     //how to do it in here to create element 
     //<my-element name='name1'></my-element>
   }
}
```

I looked this link https://gist.run/?id=762c00133d5d5be624f9, but it needs a container reference
`<div ref="container"></div>`

I dont want to specify a container, instead I want it to be append to current view.

I also tried using aurelia-compiler from https://github.com/gooy/aurelia-compiler, when I try to import it, it was able to locate file'gooy/aurelia-compiler', but I got this error:
Error invoking Compiler. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?

Can someone please help? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could inject the view's html element and use it as a "container". Like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ViewFactory} from './view-factory';

@inject(Element, ViewFactory)
export class App {
  //...

  constructor(element, viewFactory) {
    this.element = element;
    this.viewFactory = viewFactory
  }
}
```

Then, use `this.element` in the insert method:

```
this.dispose = this.viewFactory.insert(this.element, this.viewHtml, viewModel);
```

Running example:

https://gist.run/?id=9d5e7a60cd02e55618829a304df00621

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, this really helps! I have thought of passing element, but I didn't. Better of trying everything.

Comment: Wow, short and sweet demo (the gist). I haven't seen it often here.

Comment: Hi Fabio, could you also show me how to use a class as viewModel please, in this example would be my-element.js(which has import and class ...etc inside) file, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to manually inject views through your viewModel (controller), try creating new viewModels from which to generate views. So, like this:

**home.html**

```
<template>
    <my-element repeat.for="name of names" name.bind="name"></my-element>
    <button click.delegate="addName()">Create My Element</button>
</template>
```

**home.js**

```
export class HomeViewModel {

    constructor() {
        this.names = []
    }

    addName() {
        this.names.push('Jim');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply